# Is there a way to remove elements from $\Bbb{Z}$ and create a related ring structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For example.  Everyone hates $3$, so let's remove it all-together from $\Bbb{Z}$: Let $\Bbb{Z}' = \Bbb{Z} - 3\Bbb{Z}$.    Then is there a way to keep it a ring, i.e. $\Bbb{Z}'$ forms a ring by redefining $+$ somehow?  By that I mean not too much as obviously any infinite set can be turned into an additive group.  But for instance, something like, if $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}', a + b \in 3\Bbb{Z} \implies a + b := 0$.  Something simple like that.

Comment: Well, you've killed the additive identity, which isn't a good sign. Are you sure you don't want to consider the quotient ring?

Edit: okay, you definitely want the quotient ring. Do you know how that's defined?

Comment: @IanColey no way, needs to be infinite.  You're telling me that a related structure to $\Bbb{Z}$ doesn't reside in $\Bbb{Z} - 3\Bbb{Z}$.  That's *shocking* to me....

Comment: What is your recommendation for the new additive identity element in $\mathbb Z\setminus 3\mathbb Z$?

Comment: One can [transport the structure](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242) of any ring onto any set of the same cardinality. So if you want  an answer less trivial than that, then you need to specify what you desire preserved in the process.

Comment: Ian Coley: You're literally asking him what he's asking you. I feel like that's not very helpful.

Comment: @SamuelYusim No other element acts *multiplicatively* the way zero does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_i, i=1...n$ be a subset of the set $P$ of all primes such that that the set of the other primes $P'=P-\{p_i, i=1...n\}$ is infinite. Let $\mathbb Z'=\mathbb Z-\cup \mathbb p_iZ$. Then you can turn $\mathbb Z'$ into a ring while retaining $\mathbb Z$'s multiplication structure and redefining $+$ as follows:

Since $P$ and $P'$ have the same cardinality there exists a bijection $f: P \to P'$. Extend $f$ to map $0\to 0$, $1\to 1$, and to all integers by mapping $\Pi_j p_j^{k_j}\to \Pi_j f(p_j)^{k_j}$. This obviously preserves multiplication structure.

Then introduce the addition operation: for $a,b\in \mathbb Z'$ define $a+_{\mathbb Z'}b=f(f^{-1}a+_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}b)$.

It only remains to check whether $\times_{\mathbb Z'}$ is associative relative to $+_{\mathbb Z'}$:

$(a+_{\mathbb Z'}b)\times_{\mathbb Z'} c=f(f^{-1}a+_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}b)\times_{\mathbb Z'} f(f^{-1}c)=f((f^{-1}a+_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}b)\times_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}c)=f(f^{-1}a\times_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}c+_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}b\times_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}c)=f(f^{-1}(a\times_{\mathbb Z'}c)+_{\mathbb Z}f^{-1}(b\times_{\mathbb Z'}c))=a\times_{\mathbb Z'}c+_{\mathbb Z'}b\times_{\mathbb Z'}c$

Comment: This answer assumes that you've added ${0}$ back into $\mathbb{Z}'$.

Comment: @Michael Is this new structure isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$?  I think it is:  $f(a + b) = f(f^{-1}a' + f^{-1}b')$ for some $a', b' \in \Bbb{Z}'$ so $ = a' +_{\Bbb{Z}} b' = f(a) +f(b)$.  $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Also works if you remove certain infinite subsets of $P$. The key is that we need infinitely many primes to remain.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: yes, this is an isomorphism.

Comment: @EnjoysMath The method used above is a special case of the method of [transporting structure](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242) that I mentioned in a comment to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a (rather clunky) way of putting an additive structure on ${\Bbb Z}-3{\Bbb Z}$:
$$m\oplus n=\Bigl\lceil\frac{m+n+1}{3}\Bigr\rceil
  +\Bigl\lceil\frac{2m+2n+2}{3}\Bigr\rceil-1\ .$$
Doesn't make a ring structure with ordinary multiplication though, you need to redefine multiplication too, and I think it will look even worse than addition ;-)