# Ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

Is there a possibilty to define a (nontrivial) ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$) other than the usual so that $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$) with that structure becomes an integral domain (or even UFD, PID or euclidean) but not a field?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is not a field. What do you mean by 'other'? Non-isomorphic perhaps?

Comment: My memories of ring algebra is very foggy so I don't dare put this as an answer. My intuition is that such a ring structure does not exist. Assume it exists and denotes $Z$ this ring structure (i.e. a countable integral domain that is not a field and not isomorph to $\mathbb Z$). Then $Z$ has a field of fractions denoted $Q$. By construction, $Q$ has characteristic $0$ and the subring ${\mathbb Z}1_Q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. But this subring ${\mathbb Z}1_Q$ is just $Z$, hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Let $E$ denote your favourite countable Euclidean domain that is not a field, say $\mathbb{Z}[i].$ Since $E$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are both countable, there is a bijection $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow E$. Now define a binary operation $+_*$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by writing

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}(x+_*y = f^{-1}(f(x)+_E f(y)))$$

Similarly for all the other ring operations / constants. You'll end up with an ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ that is isomorphic to $E$.

Comment: This is sometimes called [transport of structure.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242)