# Looking for operations by which the set of natural numbers becomes a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am interested in finding an operation on the set of [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) by which $\mathbb{N}$ becomes a group. I am not able to think of any example.

Comment: Have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group#Examples:_the_integers,_the_Grothendieck_group_of_a_manifold_and_of_a_ring and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction

Comment: That means with any operation we cannot from it as group

Comment: I don't know of any binary operation by which the natural numbers become a group.

Comment: Multiplication of [nimbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber), maybe?

Comment: The positive, negative integers and zero  form a group under addition. 0 is the identity element.  The non-negative integers by themselves  form a semi-group under both addition and multiplication..

Comment: Lookup **transport of structure**, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242) and [many more examples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure)

Comment: @jack , the confusion of this post is really the special structure of the natural number. By making more emphasis on it, isnt that make the post more confusing?

Comment: @ArcticChar: The Wikipedia link may be unnecessary. I have done my part of editing anyway. And yes, one should pay attention that one is talking about the *set* $\mathbb{N}$ of natural number, not any other extra "structure" on the set $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 11):

There are many of them. my favourite is the [nimber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) addition, also known as bitwise exclusive or. In fact, there’s even a corresponding multiplication operation that makes the finite nimbers into a quadratically closed field.

Of course, there are also a bunch of boring ones based on bijections between ℕ and any group of size $\aleph_0$, such as $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{A}$.

Comment: What would be a reference for the definition of the subtraction of nimbers?

Comment: @Pierre nimbers are their own inverse, so it is the same as the addition.

Answer (score 5):

Every group with countable elements induces a group structure on $\mathbb{N}$. Asume that $(A,+,0,-)$ is a group and $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ is countable, w.l.o.g $a_1=0$ and $f(a_n)=n$ and $f^{-1}(n)=a_n$ then we define an addition $\oplus$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by

$$n\oplus m:=f(a_n+a_m)$$
and a neutral element
$$\circledcirc:=f(a_1)$$
and an inverse
$$\ominus n:=f(-a_n)$$

So for example $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 0, -)$ is a group.
$$f(1)=0\\
f(2n)=n\\
f(2n+1)=-n$$

so for the $\mathbb{N}$ we have the following

The neutral element is $1$ and so 
$$n\oplus1=n$$
Te addition is defined by 
$$2m \oplus 2n=2(m+n)$$
$$(2m+1)\oplus(2n+1)=2(m+n)+1$$
$$(2m+1)\oplus2n=2(n-m), \text{if} \;n>m$$
$$(2m+1)\oplus2n=2(m-n)+1, \text{if} \;n\le m$$
we have 
$$\ominus (2n)=2n+1$$
$$\ominus (2n+1)=2n$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The precise answer depends on [whether the natural numbers include zero](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), but such an operation exists either way.  If the natural numbers include zero, then as Simone says nimber addition works; the inversion operation is just the identity in this case.  If we adopt a definition that does not include zero, then nimber multiplication qualifies.  See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) for a set theory based definition of both operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection between the natural numbers and the integers, for example:

$0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3$....

And the integers are a group for addition.