# Question conncerning how to show ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the following ring isomorophism question:

Let $\mathbb{Z}^{*}$ be n integral domain defined by the following operations:

$a\oplus b=a+b-1$ 
$a\odot b=a+b-ab$,

where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{*}$ are isomorphic.

I need to construct a homorophic bijective function $\phi(x)$ which maps $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^{*}$

$\phi(x)$ is a one variable function but both $a\odot b$ and $a\oplus b$ are binary operation consisting of two element.  I am assuming that when either $a\odot b$ or $a\oplus b$ and gets plugged into $\phi(x)$, it is treated as a single variable.  But because of the following property of homomorphism: $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$, I can write $\phi(a \odot b)$ in terms of $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$

Also, I know of the following facts after doing some calculations.

$a\oplus 1=a$ 
$a\oplus 1-a =0$ 
$a\odot 1=1$ 
$a\odot 0=a$ 
$a\odot \frac{-a}{1-a}=0$

The function $\phi(x)=1-x$ is the supposed function. The supposed function seems to be found by making use of the additive zero element/multiplicative identity $1$ and let $a\odot b=1$ so that $1 - a\odot b=(1-a)(1-b)$. We then obtain $\phi(a\odot b) = \phi(a)\odot \phi(b)=(1-a)(1-b)$.  What I want to ask is, is this a general strategy I can use for showing isomorphism between other rings, where one of the rings are defined by a different set of defined addition and multiplication operations.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Besides the dupes, see also [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_definitions_of_mathematical_structures#Transport_of_structures;_isomorphism)

Comment: @BillDubuque i am not familiar with "transport of structure" in the context of rings.  It seems like a concept that is not talked about in many algebra text.

Comment: It's often implicit in the discussion of isomorphisms of algebraic structures (and sometimes explicit in exercises).

Comment: Btw, this "circle composition" has applications to results around the Jacobson radical (search on those keywords to learn more).

Comment: @BillDubuque i still don't understand what transporting of structure is in the context of showing isomorphism between different algebraic structure.  I mean is it some kind of technique.  I managed to find two algebra books that have this phrase.  None of them give any examples.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did further look up onlline.  I was not able to find any information on how the bijective function is found. The solution inthe text just says that "a good guess for the function/.." , should not there be some sort of systematic way of going about it?

Comment: As I explained in the linked dupes, it arises by transporting the algebraic structure along *any bijection* of the underlying sets. Though any bijection works,  usually in algebra we are interested in one having some innate algebraic structure, e.g. the class group example I mention at the end [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242).